# Symfony Sonata Page Bundle with TranslatableInterface (TranslationBundle + sf 3.4)

Tags: symfony, sonata

I am trying to add translations of pages and blocks for Page Bundle. I cannot find any information in the documentation. Can somebody help me with tips on integration with TranslationBundle, or a piece of code?

My Page Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Project\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\BasePage as BasePage;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\TranslatableInterface;
use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Traits\Gedmo\PersonalTranslatableTrait;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\AppBundle\Repository\PageRepository")
 */
class Page extends BasePage implements TranslatableInterface
{
    use PersonalTranslatableTrait;

    /**
     * @var int $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @var PageTranslation[]|ArrayCollection */
    private $translations;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

My Entity PageTranslation:

```
<?php
namespace Project\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\AbstractPersonalTranslation;

class PageTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $locale
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $content
     */
    public function __construct($locale = null, $field = null, $content = null)
    {
        $this->setLocale($locale);
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($content);
    }

    protected $object;
}
```

My PageBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Page.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://Atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-3.0.xsd"
                  xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">    
    <entity
        name="Project\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page"
        table="page__page"
        repository-class="Project\AppBundle\Repository\PageRepository"
        >

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

        <attribute-overrides>
            <attribute-override name="name">
                <field column="name">
                    <gedmo:translatable/>
                </field>
            </attribute-override>
        </attribute-overrides>

        <one-to-many field="translations" target-entity="Project\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\PageTranslation" mapped-by="object" />

        <gedmo:translatable field="name"/>
        <gedmo:translation entity="Project\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\PageTranslation" locale="locale"/>

    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

My PageBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/PageTranslation.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity
            name="Project\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\PageTranslation"
            table="page__page_translations"
    >
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>

        <field name="locale" length="8" />
        <field name="field" length="32" />
        <field name="content" type="text" nullable="true"/>

        <many-to-one field="object" target-entity="Project\Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\Page" inversed-by="translations">
            <join-column name="object_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" />
        </many-to-one>

        <unique-constraints>
            <unique-constraint columns="locale,object_id,field"></unique-constraint>
        </unique-constraints>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

I'm starting with symfony, so I will be grateful for any help.